# how to link static library from gradle subproject in application subproject

Tags: c++, gradle

I have a project structure like this:

```
MyProject/  
├── gradle.build  
├── gradle.settings  
├── MyCppApp/  
|   ├── gradle.build  
|   ├── gradle.settings  
│   └── src/  
|       └── main/  
|           └── cpp/  
|               └── my_cpp_app.cpp  
└── MyCppLib/  
    ├── gradle.build  
    ├── gradle.settings  
    └── src/  
        ├── main/  
        |   ├── cpp/  
        |   |   └── my_cpp_lib.h
        |   └── public/
        |       └── my_cpp_lib.h
        └── test/
            └── cpp/
                └── my_cpp_lib_test.cpp
```

My gradle files:

`settings.gradle`

```
include 'MyCppLib'
include 'MyCppApp'
```

`build.gradle`

```
configure(':MyCppApp') {
    dependencies {
//        compile project(':MyCppLib')   <-- this does not work
    }
}
```

`MyCppApp/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: "cpp-application"


dependencies {
//    compile project(':MyCppLib')  <-- this does not work
}
```

`MyCppLib/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: "cpp-library"
apply plugin: "cpp-unit-test"


library {
    linkage = [Linkage.STATIC]
}
```

I tired `compile project(':MyCppLib')` in both shown places, and also `implementation project(':MyCppLib')`. The error is always that the corresponding function is not found, but in my understanding, the tasks should automatically added by the plugins.
I expect a simple solution, as the goal is obvious but besides some android project im very new to gradle and was not able to figgure it out jet.

Answer (score 0):

So finally i found the answer by myself and its quite simple.

in `MyCppApp/build.gradle`

it has to be

```
apply plugin: "cpp-application"

application {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':MyCppLib')
    }
}
```